# Eclipse: scroll space below code

Tags: eclipse

is there any plugin for eclipse to add some space below the code so that I can scroll the last line up to half the screen / up to the top? I hate it when the line I am writing on is always on the bottom of my screen.
Of course, I could add these lines myself, but that would also mean that I have to remove them later, and I don't feel comfortable with so many empty lines...

If there is no such plugin, would it be easy to write one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest as you are saying adding these lines manually and in the end hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` to format your code which also includes removing those empty lines at the bottom.